# Getting error while accessing rally using rally-rest-api-2.1.2.jar

Tags: rest, api, rally

I am getting an authentication error for API key in rally. Even api key is given full access.

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 401 Full authentication is required to access this resource 
at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.executeRequest(HttpClient.java:163)
at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doRequest(HttpClient.java:145)
at com.rallydev.rest.client.ApiKeyClient.doRequest(ApiKeyClient.java:37)
at com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient.doGet(HttpClient.java:221)
at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.query(RallyRestApi.java:168)
```

This is The code :

```
String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
restApi.setApplicationName(projectname);

QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("Testsets");

if(null !=workspace && ""!=workspace)
    testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspace);

QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Hi @mayank jain, were you able to able to fix, i am using rally node api and facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I would check for is whether you are inside a corporate network that uses authenticated proxy servers. Unless you configure the connection correctly, the proxy will reject your request before it even gets to Rally.

Second thing I just thought of is, whether you are setting the right field in the header to enable the use of an APIKey. The Rally servers expect the ZSESSIONID to be set to the APIKey, I believe.